# I want to stitch multiple videos with openCV in C++

Tags: c++, opencv, video

Here is the thing:

I wanted to stitch some video files using openCV in C++ environment.

Here some code that I tried:

```
while (1)
{
    Mat frame,frame2,frame3,copy1,copy2,copy3;

    vector< Mat > vFrame;

    cap >> frame;
    cap2 >> frame2;
    cap3 >> frame3;
    cap.read(frame);
    resize(frame, frame, Size(320, 240), 0, 0, INTER_CUBIC);
    cap2.read(frame2);
    resize(frame2, frame2, Size(320, 240), 0, 0, INTER_CUBIC);
    cap3.read(frame3);
    resize(frame3, frame3, Size(320, 240), 0, 0, INTER_CUBIC);

    frame.copyTo(copy1);
    frame2.copyTo(copy2);
    frame3.copyTo(copy3);

    vFrame.push_back(copy1);
    vFrame.push_back(copy2);
    vFrame.push_back(copy3);

    if (frame.empty())
        break;
    Stitcher stitcher = Stitcher::createDefault(true);

    stitcher.stitch(vFrame, frame);

    //video.write(frame);

    imshow("Frame", frame);

 }
```

It shows the needed ouput **but** I get really low FPS. I don't know why. Could anyone help?

Can the `cv2::Stitcher::stitch` do really stitch multiple videos file or I must use another OpenCV method to read every frame of the videos and stitch it?

Comment: Your code has a problem where every time you enter the loop you read a frame from each video and throw it away `cap >> frame;` and `cap.read(frame);` both do the same thing.
https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a473055e77dd7faa4d26d686226b292c1

Comment: i already remove that but still got slow performance

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, This is supposed to give you a very low framerate**

I have done exactly this thing in the past, and I can tell you from experience that the Stitcher function takes **forever** to stitch three videos at the same time.

**There are however ways to speed it up**

[This answer](http://answers.opencv.org/question/12753/the-opencv-stitcher-is-very-slow/) on opencv.org provides a few ways to get you started:

1. The feature detection for each image is run within a for loop in the
   example. This could be parellelised to run on multiple cores as
   getting the features in each image is independent.
2. There are appear to be some GPU capabilities for SURF and I think
   other places within Stitching.
3. What resolution are you using for the image registration stage? Can
   this be lowered without affecting performance?
4. What resolution are you using for the composition stage? Can this be
   lowered and still give you adequate panorama? I've found that this
   can affect performance a lot.

Comment: i already tried to resizing the data, still no luck with stitching videos, it get really low FPS and also the result is not good